# Add TeX code in files produced by the estout command

Tags: stata, tex

I am using the *community-contributed* `estout` command to produce `TeX` files with regression results and I am wondering if it is possible to add additional `TeX` lines to these files.

More specifically, I want to add the following lines to the beginning of the produced file:

```
\documentclass[leqno,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
```

I would also like to add the following line to the end of the file:

```
\end{document}
```

I am asking this because I will produce the same table repeatedly and I want to look at the compiled `pdf` instead of the `TeX` code each time I run a regression.

The *community-contributed* command `tabout` has the option I described above.

Does `estout` have a similar option?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get what you want is to write a program that uses the `file` command to create a composite mark-up document:

```
program define mytex
version 14

local texfile "`1'"

tempname myreadfile mywritefile

file open `mywritefile' using "new_`texfile'", write replace text

file write `mywritefile' "\documentclass[leqno,11pt]{article}" _newline
file write `mywritefile' "\usepackage{booktabs}" _newline
file write `mywritefile' "\usepackage{tabularx}" _newline
file write `mywritefile' "\begin{document}" _newline
file write `mywritefile' _newline

file close `mywritefile'

file open `myreadfile' using "`texfile'", read text
file open `mywritefile' using "new_`texfile'", write append text

file read `myreadfile' line
file write `mywritefile' `"`line'"' _newline

while r(eof) == 0 {
    file read `myreadfile' line
    file write `mywritefile' `"`line'"' _newline
}

file close `myreadfile'
file close `mywritefile'

file open `mywritefile' using "new_`texfile'", write append text
file write `mywritefile' "\end{document}" _newline
file close `mywritefile'

end
```

Now suppose you have an `estout`-produced `TeX` file `example.tex` with the following contents:

```
. type example.tex

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Here is the text of your introduction.

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation}
    \alpha = \sqrt{ \beta }
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Write your subsection text here.

\section{Conclusion}
Write your conclusion here.
```

By running this little program you get a file `new_example.tex`:

```
. mytex example.tex

. type new_example.tex  
\documentclass[leqno,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Here is the text of your introduction.

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation}
    \alpha = \sqrt{ \beta }
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Write your subsection text here.

\section{Conclusion}
Write your conclusion here.


\end{document}
```

The contents of the source `TeX` file (from `estout`) can be any `TeX` mark-up, of course.

---

**EDIT:**

As the OP now mentions in the comments, `estout` has `prehead` and `postfoot` options for adding text before and after the produced table. These appear to support `TeX` mark-up.

However, the solution presented here is much more flexible (e.g. for multiple lines), extensible and of course it is generalizable beyond `estout`.

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just find out there is prehead and postfoot options in the estout. I am still learning to write a reproducible answer.

Comment: You are correct, although this must be a recent addition. I suspect that with one-line headings and footnotes it will be sufficient, but for multiple lines i still think my solution is much more flexible and generalizable beyond `estout`.